# git-cheetah modifying path environment variable multiple times

Tags: windows, git

Just wanna find out if anyone has had a similar experience to this.
Git seems to be modifying my path environment variable, hereafter referred to as $path, such that if after having my system running for a few days the $path is 1 huge mess!

After a clean boot $path looks something like this:

> D:\WINDOWS\system32;D:\WINDOWS;D:\Apps\Development\Git\cmd;D:\Apps\Development\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;D:\Apps\Development\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows;D:\Apps\Tools\GnuWin32\bin

When it gets to the state I mentioned it looks something like this:

> D:\Apps\Development\Git\git-cheetah..\bin;D:\WINDOWS\system32;D:\WINDOWS;D:\Apps\Development\Git\cmd;D:\Apps\Development\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;D:\Apps\Development\phantomjs-1.9.7-windows;D:\Apps\Tools\GnuWin32\bin

Except that the *D:\Apps\Development\Git\git-cheetah..\bin* bit is repeated, sometimes (what looks like) over 50 times!

Any insight into this would be much appreciated

Comment: I'm running into the exact same thing. I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: I note that there is a bug for it on the github project

Answer (score 2):

First of all, apologies that this is more of a workaround than an answer.  I am experiencing the same exact issue.  Eventually my PATH gets so large that my programs can't find anything, even as simple as XCOPY.

This is happening to me on my work computer which is under domain control and I don't have admin permissions.  These instructions assume no admin access, strictly user access.

In order to avoid restarting I perform the following:

Prior to performing these steps you can open command window and run `set PATH` to verify that you have too many `cheetah`s.

1. Go to the Environment Variables dialog (Right-Click "My Computer" -> Choose "Properties" -> Select the "Advanced" tab -> Click the "Environment Variables" button).
2. Select "PATH" variable under the "User variables for `<username>`" section.
3. Click then "Edit" button under the same section.
4. Do nothing
5. Click OK in the "Edit User Variable" dialog box.
6. Click OK in the "Environment Variables" dialog box.
7. Click OK in the "System Properties" window.

Open a NEW command window (command windows that were already open may preserve their current environment) and run 'set PATH' to verify that you're back to none or one 'cheetah's in your path.

Comment: I actually figured out that using the Environment Variables dialog kinda resets any future consoles. But was hoping someone would kno how to prevent it in the 1st place.
Only difference is that I had to do it with the System PATH variable as there isnt a User PATH variable. Im on XP r u maybe using something later?

It is actually quite a stupid thing which sucks coz GIT is so awesome. I do hav a theory tho: I think it happens with the more repos u have

Comment: I have 2 or 3 repositories only, and the path is repeated 59 times in my PATH variable.

Comment: I'm seeing it too. Perhaps it happens the more you right-click in Explorer, so the git context menu comes up.

Comment: It's strange to me that this workaround works. Also, it's not just when you right click and open the CMD from the context menu.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same annoying problem. Just download git-cheetah source, open common/winexec.c and on line 262 change from:

```
if (path.len) {
    setenv("PATH", path.buf, 1);
    rec->envpath = strbuf_detach(&path, NULL);
}
```

to:

```
if (path.len) {
    if (!strstr(getenv("PATH"), gitpath))
        setenv("PATH", path.buf, 1);
    rec->envpath = strbuf_detach(&path, NULL);
}
```

Then, recompile (cd explorer, mingw32-make) and copy the generated dll over the existing one in Program files\Git\git-cheetah. If the file is in use you can open a console window, close the Explorer process and copy using command line; then, restart explorer using the task manager (File->Execute).

Comment: Not sure why this is not the accepted answer. Works perfectly on Windows 10 VS 2015.